# Timeout when trying to delete a record

Tags: php, sqlite, runtime-error, sql-delete

The weirdest thing happened today. When I run this query:

`DELETE FROM some_table WHERE id IN(5)`

I get a 30 second timeout error in PHP. The same query runs without issues on my local development server, but when I move it to the production server, I get the timeout.

No sqlite error or anything like that, just *"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded "* :|

What could be the problem? Is there any way I could debug this at least?

Comment: Do you have a large amount of rows on the table? Using IN(5) means it will literally look over every row even after it finds a result. You should likely change that to WHERE ID = '5' LIMIT 1. Using the literal = should speed you up, and LIMIT 1 drops the query after the first success. Without the limit it has to look over every single row to ensure no others equal 5. I'm not 100% positive if SQL will drop automatically if it is a primary/unique key.

Comment: No, there are just 5 records. But the `id` column is a foreign key inside another table with ~100K records. The other table has ON DELETE CASCADE on it. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Uhu. Now you have 5 rows that it has to compare each one against the 100K rows, which means it has to index 500K plus rows.

Comment: I see... Is there any way I could speed this up? Would it run faster if I deleted records from the other table first? The column with the foreign key is indexed

Comment: You'll likely have to drop the table to accomplish that, as the foreign key constraint will balk if you try to delete the rows. I would try using DELETE FROM some_table WHERE ID = '5' LIMIT 1 and see if you have any better luck. If you have access to a command line terminal, running your script there will bypass the execution limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In top of all my new codes I put this function

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',60);
```

[reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) .

to debug my script execute time I use this

```
$start = microtime(true);
function execute(){global $start;$end = microtime(true);$time=number_format(($end - $start), 5);return$time;}
//..... your code here 
echo '<br><b>.'Page Loaded In 'execute().' Seconds<b/>';
```